# HTML5 number type input not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, html

how can I stop user to NOT type value more than max and min attributes. Though constrains are working fine if user change values from arrows in right corner.

Note: I have option to use angularjs

```html
  <input type="number" max="3" value="2" min="0" />
```

Comment: You can use Angular to achieve this with extra work. The min/max directives will validate the input, although they allow the user to type values outside of the constraints, marking the model as invalid. 
I can think of a number of different ways to prevent the user typing a value outside of the constraints all of which involve checking the value in code and updating it to the max/min as appropriate. For example you could check on change, blur, watch the model for updates, etc. (I assume you are familiar with Angular).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not a direct answer to your question, but an alternative idea as it may not be a wise idea just blocking intentional user input (confusion and frustration may arise if you don't give the proper feedback (is this keyboard working?); you might need to play a sound, or shake the input field a little depending on the OS your user is on).

You can style wrong inputs using the `:invalid` pseudo selector (and some browsers already add some styling by default)

```css
  input:invalid { background: #f00; }
```

```html
  <input type="number" max="3" value="2" min="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought angular is a little overkill

html code:

```
 <input type="number" max="3" value="2" min="0" id="myNumInput"/>
```

jQuery code:

```
  $('#myNumInput').keyup(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this)
    var MAX_VALUE = Number($this.prop('max'))
    var MIN_VALUE = Number($this.prop('min'))

    var val = $this.val()
    if (val.trim() === '' || 
        isNaN(val) ||
        Number(val) > MAX_VALUE ||
        Number(val) < MIN_VALUE) {
      // if the value is invalid, set it to MIN, it depends on your decision, feel free to modify the code here
      $this.val(MIN_VALUE)
    }
    else {
      // convert a string to a number format
      $this.val(Number(val))
    }
  })
```